# Can you help me to provide stable version of @nguniversal?

Tags: angular

I am using @nguniversal since last 6 month since I have seen multiple issue in it. moreover i found like after some week or month. the application is getting failed due to some version dependency.

I have below package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "data-science-python",
  "version": "1.2.0",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN LICENSE.pdf",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "prestart": "ng build",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod --no-aot && ng build --prod --app 1 --output-hashing=false",
    "build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles",
    "webpack:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
    "serve:prerender": "cd dist/browser && http-server",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/server"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.0",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^0.4.5",
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "5.0.0-beta.5",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "5.0.0-beta.5",
    "@ngx-meta/core": "5.0.0",
    "@ngx-share/button": "^5.0.1",
    "@ngx-share/buttons": "^5.0.1",
    "@ngx-share/core": "^5.0.1",
    "angular2-disqus": "^6.1.1",
    "angular2-highlight-js": "^6.0.1-alpha",
    "animate.css": "^3.5.2",
    "arrive": "^2.3.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.5",
    "bootstrap-notify": "^3.1.3",
    "bootstrap-select": "^1.12.2",
    "bootstrap-tagsinput": "^0.7.1",
    "chartist": "0.11.0",
    "chartist-plugin-zoom": "^0.4.0",
    "chartjs-plugin-zoom": "^0.5.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "datatables": "1.10.12",
    "datatables.net-bs": "1.10.12",
    "datatables.net-buttons": "^1.5.1",
    "datatables.net-responsive": "^2.1.1",
    "domready": "^1.0.8",
    "eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "4.17.47",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "firebase": "^4.8.1",
    "firebase-admin": "~5.4.2",
    "firebase-functions": "0.7.1",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "fullcalendar": "^3.4.0",
    "googleapis": "^19.0.0",
    "grpc": "^1.8.0",
    "jasny-bootstrap": "^3.1.3",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "mathjax": "^2.7.3",
    "ng2-adsense": "^5.1.4",
    "ng2-slim-loading-bar": "^4.0.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.1",
    "ngx-disqus": "^2.3.7",
    "nouislider": "^9.2.0",
    "npm": "^5.7.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "rxjs": "5.5.6",
    "ts-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "twitter-bootstrap-wizard": "^1.2.0",
    "validate": "^3.0.1",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/bootstrap": "3.3.32",
    "@types/chartist": "0.9.34",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/jquery": "1.10.31",
    "@types/node": "^8.0.30",
    "cpy-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~3.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.5.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
    "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.6"
  }
}
```

Kindly, help me to choose the stable version and suggestion for server side rendering

Answer (score 0):

use these npm commands

```
 >npm i -g npm-check-updates
```

then `>ncu -a` to update your package.json
 then >`npm install`

the above command should help you install latest packages.